# Can I select any of my published paper in journal for book chapter

Tags: journals, books

I have been invited to submit a book chapter. The invitation email says:

> Due to your involvement in the field, and the research you published in your paper, 'X', publisher 'Y' invites you to extend your work and offer a more comprehensive overview of your studies. Contribute a chapter to 'Z', an upcoming Open Access book edited by Dr.'W'.

Surprisingly, paper 'X' is completely unrelated to the Book 'Z'. The book is edited by a renowned professor, the publisher is InTechOpen.

What to do in such case? Can I select any of my published papers in journal for this purpose? Will it not create any copyright problems?

Comment: Who owns the copyright for your journal paper?

Comment: This can only be answered by whoever gave you the invitation. What is their view of the book. I'm sure it isn't just random stuff.

Comment: First of all, make sure that this is a legitimate invitation from a reputable source, and not a [scam](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/126337) by a [predatory](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/71783) [publisher](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2513/). (See the 3 links for more details.)

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: You did not name the publisher, but I recognize the wording. I have the exact same email in my own spam folder. See: [What is the consenus of IntechOpen, open access books, are they predatory?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/117476/).

Comment: @Buffy: Actually, given what else we know about this "publisher", I am pretty sure it *is* just random stuff.

Comment: "The book is edited by a renowned professor ...". **Prove it.**

Answer (score 33):

If they're sending you invitations to contribute to volumes that are completely unrelated to your work, the next step's simple: ignore the email. They're clearly not doing their research and are resorting to mass mailings.

Comment: +1, I was just about to post the same answer.  I get such emails all the time.  They are clearly just spam of no academic merit - they simply want to get you to pay the "open access processing fees" that they will charge.

Comment: And the fees are nothing to sneeze at: 1400 GBP for a book chapter, according to [their website](https://www.intechopen.com/page/OA-publishing-fees). Save your money (and reputation), and just ignore them.

Comment: Ignore all emails from InTechOpen.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker Wow. Reputable publishers pay *you*, not the other way round.

Answer (score 8):

Normally, when getting an invitation to submit a book chapter, the expectation is that you submit a *novel* piece of work, unless stated otherwise.

Submitting a paper already published will not satisfy this requirement. There are two problems with this: 1) you often give the copyright to a publisher after the acceptance of your paper for publication. For a republication, you would need the permission from the publisher then, which is unlikely to be granted. 2) This will look like you are trying to publish the same result twice, which is frowned upon.

Comment: Actually my area of research is completely different from the topic of the book. I don't know why that invitation came to me. What to do in such case ?

Comment: @richard-williams This "invitation" is not real. It's a mass-produced email sent to thousands of people whose addresses were scraped from publications and academic web sites. If you accept it, you will actively harm your career. Ignore it, and send similar emails to your junk email folder.

Comment: @iayork: The book is edited by a renowned professor, the publisher is Intechopen.

Comment: If you want to proceed, email the "renowned professor" (at an email address you find, not the one in the email you received) and ask if they're genuinely associated with it. These emails typically fake the editor names. Even if the "renowned professor" is actually associated with it, all that shows is that senior people can also be fooled by scammers.

Comment: @RIchardWilliams According to their website, intechopen have almost 107,000 "authors and editors". You are not joining an elite club here.

Comment: Since the asker has edited the question to indicate that the publisher is predatory, this answer is now incorrect.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I would not say incorrect - it's still the answer to the question in the title. It's just not what the asker should *actually do* in this specific case.